# I get 'pypyodbc.DatabaseError' repeatedly

Tags: python, pypyodbc

I have two **.py** files

## File_1 contains the following statements:

```
try:
        conStr4SQLserver = pypyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};'
                                            'SERVER=........'
                                            'DATABASE=......'
                                            'UID=......;PWD=......')
    except:
        print("I am unable to connect to the SQL SERVER Database")
```

## File_2 contains the following statements:

```
import AnotherPythonFile as FindClosest

def query(queryStr,fetchOption = 'GetAll'):     # Default value of the parameter fetchOption is 'GetAll' 

    global sqlException
    sqlException = False
    try:
        connection = FindClosest.conStr4SQLserver
        cursr = connection.cursor()

        cursr.execute(queryStr)
        if fetchOption == 'GetOne':
            rows = cursr.fetchone()
        else: 
            rows = cursr.fetchall()

        return rows
    except:
        sqlException = True
        print("Error: Exception Ocured in Function 'query' :", sys.exc_info()[0])
```

Here's how I call the 'query' function: `firstrow= query(queryStr, 'GetOne')`

However, in case of an exception, I need to call the query function again. 
I recall the function in the following way:

```
while (sqlException):
        firstrow= query(queryStr, 'GetOne')
```

Unfortunately, I keep on getting the `<class 'pypyodbc.DatabaseError'>` each time the loop executes.

Can you please tell me where the problem is?